# Is there a limit to the number of short link for Firebase Dynamic Link?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Are there any upper limit on the number of short URL that can be created in Firebase Dynamic link?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create#create-a-dynamic-link-from-parameters

Such as shortened URL is made in units from hundreds to thousands per a day...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no documented limit to the number of short links you can make in a day. But the service is monitored for abusive behavior.

From the comments: If your use case involves creating hundreds of short links per second, it is best to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to discuss your requirements.

Comment: Frank, this is correct. At the same time there is a limit how many requests per second you can make. This number is quite high. If use case involves creation hundreds of short links per second, it is best to reach to Firebase Support to discuss your requirements.

Comment: Quick update after syncing with teammates.

Here you can find quota for Firebase Dynamic Links REST API https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest (see very bottom). iOS and Android shortening API are sharing the same quota.

From there:

Requests are limited to 50 queries per second and 100,000 queries per day. If exceeded, then the response will return HTTP error code 429. To request for more quota, fill out this form.

Comment: what about hundreds per day? i think my app will create around 100-1000 links per day

Answer (score 19):

The quota is listed in the [Dynamic Links documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest):

> Requests are limited to <strike>50 queries per second</strike> 5 requests/IP address/second, and <strike>100,000</strike> 200,000 queries per day. If exceeded, then the response will return HTTP error code 429.
>
> To request for more quota, fill out this [form](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfPS2BfT5x9nwYrnQIrqu8Pzgcy2XF45Uv8ZsqBoL4RFEoQNg/viewform).

So, up to 5 requests/IP address/second, and 200,000 per day. (as of August 15th 2019)